# 記する｛きする｝、 記す｛きす｝、記す｛しるす｝ - how do I use and/or differentiate between them?

Tags: word-choice

For instance, [here](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/16090/m0u/%E8%A8%98%E3%81%99/):

> 碑文に記されているところによれば

according to the inscription on the tombstone

It's listed under 記する｛きする｝. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 碑文に記されているところによれば

Without furigana, I would read this as 碑文に**しる**されているところによれば without hesitation. 記【しる】す is already a stiff word, which is suitable for the inscription on the tombstone.

記【き】する is very uncommon and sounds even stiffer to me. Probably [there is no meaningful semantic difference](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1041979795) from 記【しる】す. (Of course, there are many common compounds using 記, like 明記する, 特記する, which are not stiff nor archaic at all.)

記【き】す should be a archaic form of 記【き】する, but I think this won't be treated as a distinct verb according to the modern standard grammar.

In conclusion, I don't know why that example sentence is listed under 記【き】する. I would say it's there simply by accident.

Answer (score 0):

"記{き}す" and "記{しる}す" are almost same, but "記{しる}す" include a bit nuance of "explanation". "記{き}す" means "note down something".

> 碑文に記{き}されているところによれば From sentence written on the tombstone

another exmaple:

> 手順{てじゅん}を忘{わす}れないようにノートに記{き}す。